# How can I pre-sign puppet certificates?

Tags: cluster, puppet, cloud

[Puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/projects/puppet/) requires certificates between the client (puppet) being managed and the server (puppetmaster). You can run manually on the client and then go onto the server to sign the certificate, but how do you automate this process for clusters / cloud machines?

Comment: One corner case problem is when you re-use a hostname.  Autosigning won't solve that.  I am having this same issue.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On the server (puppetmaster) run:

```
puppetca --generate <NAME>
```

Then copy the following from the server onto the client:

```
/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/<NAME>.pem
/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem
/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/<NAME>.pem
```

If you wish to sign `<NAME>` as something other than the hostname use:

```
puppetd --fqdn=<NAME>
```

And add to /etc/puppet/puppet.conf if running the daemon

```
[puppetd]
certname=<NAME>
```

Comment: That's really useful, thanks.  I'd been puzzling over that myself.

Comment: new command is `puppet cert --generate <NAME>` see https://serverfault.com/a/457364/71452

Answer (score 6):

If you have a host database, you can use the autosign feature. In your `puppet.conf` file, in the `[puppetmasterd]`, add:

```
autosign = /path/to/autosign.conf
```

Then use a crontab to generate this file. The autosign file is just a list of hosts to autosign when they first connect to the puppetmaster. I use LDAP to configure my puppet hosts, so my cron looks like:

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/ldapsearch -x '(objectClass=puppetClient)' cn | /bin/grep ^cn | /bin/sed 's!^cn: !!' > /etc/puppet/autosign.conf
```

I'm sure people who use iClassify would be able to write a query to do the same.

Of course, you need to have some trust in the network. I use this on EC2. My puppetmaster server is in a group that only allows connections from other trusted groups. I wouldn't recommend doing this if your puppetmaster is open to the internet.

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer: automatically sign new requests. This of course is dangerous because you're blindly trusting any system that connects to your puppetmaster, which is the purpose for requiring manual signing.

```
[puppetmasterd]
autosign = true
```

You can specify false and a file to use to determine which keys to sign, too.

See the [configuration reference](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#autosign) on the Puppet wiki.

Another option is to use a tool like [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/), where you specify the puppetmaster node and create the client instance nodes, and in the task:

- Create the instance node, say with EC2's API with Ruby.
- Run puppetd on the instance, connecting to the server.
- Run puppetca --sign for the instance's request (since we know the instance name as it was given in the creation bit above).
- Run puppetd again on the instance, this time successfully connecting as the certificate is signed.

Comment: Note: If you are using Puppet 2.6 or above, the `[puppetmasterd]` section heading should now be `[master]`. See http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/tools.html for more information.

Answer (score 4):

On the server (puppetmaster) run:

```
puppetca --generate <NAME>
```

Then copy the following from the server onto the client:

```
/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/<NAME>.pem
/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem
/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/<NAME>.pem
```

If you wish to has  as something other than the hostname use:

```
puppetd --fqdn=<NAME>
```

And add to /etc/puppet/puppet.conf if running the daemon

```
[puppetd]
certname=<NAME>
```

Comment: This just seems more complicated to me. You install puppet on the client, it generates a certificate and sends it to the master for signing. When you sign it on the master, the client will start working the next time it runs. This involves less steps.

If you really want to save even this step, you can run a cron job that does something like:

for host in $(puppetca --list); do puppetca --sign $host; done

Comment: This is fine if you have one or two machines, but when you are starting and stopping machines in the cloud you don't want to have to do this manually, I can start a base machine, run a script which goes in and sets everything up via puppet without having to login to the puppet master.