# Autoaccept all Certs on Puppet Master

Tags: puppet

Is there a way I can set a puppet master to auto accept all certs from clients (so I don't have to puppetca on the master each time)?

Comment: If you have a consistent naming scheme you could presign a generate and sign a bunch of keys on the master, and then pull them to the client when you install the client the first time.  This might be a bit safer over the autosign.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/137292/how-can-i-pre-sign-puppet-certificates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file `/etc/puppet/autosign.conf` on the master, containing the domain names of the hosts for which you want certificates signed automatically.

Example:

```
www.example.com
*.example.org
*
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "*" > /etc/puppet/autosign.conf
```

Or you can be a little more secure (but not really, since a client sets its own cert name; someone wanting illegitimate access to your puppet master would just need to know what name to fake) by limiting it to a specific domain:

```
echo "*.stackexchange.com" > /etc/puppet/autosign.conf
```

Comment: This is on the master?

Comment: @KyleBrandt Yup, on the CA master.  That file is the default location (or more specifically, `$confdir/autosign.conf` is the default), but can be changed with the `autosign` setting in `puppet.conf`.

Comment: @KyleBrandt: Would you like to know more? http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/configuring.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm personally not a fan of automatically signing these certificates for the reasons already outlined.

I put together a small script kicked off during my kickstarts which runs the following:

```
echo Configuring local Puppet instance...
/usr/sbin/puppetd --waitforcert 900
sleep 10
echo We will use $HOSTNAME for all future requests...
echo Running server side script..
chvt 1
ssh -q -t $USERNAME@puppetmaster auto_client.sh $HOSTNAME
chvt 6
```

auto_client.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
NEWHOST=$1

sudo puppetca --sign $NEWHOST

if ! ( cat /etc/puppet/manifests/* | grep "$NEWHOST" )
then
    NHFILE=/etc/puppet/manifests/temp.pp
    echo node \'$NEWHOST\' >>  $NHFILE
    echo  { >> $NHFILE
    echo    include linux_base >>  $NHFILE
    echo  } >> newhost.cfg >>  $NHFILE
fi
```

I seriously thought about doing something like using a SSL certificate stored on a USB stick for the SSH connection but this proved more convenient.