# Installed puppetmaster, but why do I get "puppetca: command not found"?

Tags: puppetmaster

```
# puppetca --list
-bash: puppetca: command not found
```

I am newbie in Puppet server, but I think I have installed puppet-server correctly.

How to get the puppetca ?

Comment: What server OS? Which repository and version? For recent Ubuntu versions, `puppetmaster-common` should be pulled in as a dependency in which `/usr/sbin/puppetca` is located. And did you run it as sudo/root?

Comment: Hello fair newbie - Please spend some quality time reading [How To Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [our Meta question with tips on asking good questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault). While you got an answer on this one you will be better served in the future if you ask complete questions, and spend some time applying appropriate tags like your operating system :-)

Answer (score 9):

Starting with puppet 3.0, the [`puppetca` and other similar commands have been obsoleted](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/release_notes.html#break-deprecated-commands-are-removed). You may want to use `puppet cert list` instead.

Quoting the actual entry:

> The legacy standalone executables, which were replaced by subcommands
>   in Puppet 2.6, have been removed. Additionally, running puppet without
>   a subcommand no longer defaults to puppet apply.
>
> ```
> ┌───────────────┬───────────────────┐
> │ Pre-2.6       │ Post-2.6          │
> ├───────────────┼───────────────────┤
> │ puppetmasterd │ puppet master     │
> │ puppetd       │ puppet agent      │
> │ puppet        │ puppet apply      │
> │ puppetca      │ puppet cert       │
> │ ralsh         │ puppet resource   │
> │ puppetrun     │ puppet kick       │
> │ puppetqd      │ puppet queue      │
> │ filebucket    │ puppet filebucket │
> │ puppetdoc     │ puppet doc        │
> │ pi            │ puppet describe   │
> └───────────────┴───────────────────┘
> ```